# Longest $Scramble Sentence$?

Tags: english, open-ended, no-computers

Before we begin, allow me to define what I call a **Scramble Sentence**,

> A *Scramble Sentence* is a grammatically correct sentence, where at least 1 other permutation, of the letters in the sentence, exists that it makes a different sentence with a different meaning.

Let's define a quick restriction though, just to make sure it isn't too easy, **NO WORDS CAN BE REUSED!**

The aim of this question is to find the **longest possible sentence which fits all of the above conditions!**

Note: *Punctuation doesn't count as part of the sentence (you don't have to scramble commas and such)*

**Additional restrictions:**
* No listing out words
* No quotation marks

Comment: So basically, 3 out of every ten words have to be anagrams?

Comment: @NeedAName Not necessarily, for example, let's pretend this isn't gibberish... *Aknfr, ioif bnndeu?* and *Ionf rnaoi, ndu bne!* would be valid (if it was English, and grammatically correct!)

Comment: Yeah the wording was poor on my part, I didn't mean that having 3 anagrams per 10 words was necessary to fit the bill, but sufficient (and seemingly much easier)

Comment: You can make them arbitratily long.

Comment: Should simply rearranging the order of the words be a legitimate option? It doesn't seem to be excluded in the question i.e. The brown apron has a dog on it -> The brown dog has an apron on it are both grammatically correct with different meanings and the order of letters has changed wrt the sentence.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what a Scramble Sentence is.

Comment: The question has been changed to address your concerns

Comment: The question is not too broad with it's current restrictions...

Comment: I think an important test of whether a question is too broad is whether you can easily assess that someone has given THE correct answer or one that is clearly very difficult to beat. When asking for the longest Scramble Sentence, at what point can you mark any answer as correct? How do you know someone won't come up with a longer one 5 minutes after you accept the answer. If, instead, you said "who can come up with a 50 character Scramble Sentence first?", you will have a clear point when you can accept an answer. People may provide much longer ones as well, but there is a clear target.

Comment: @Gordon K please see [tag:open-ended]

Comment: OK - Fair point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Definitely not the longest, but getting the ball rolling.*

## 18 letters

**He bares on restraint.**
(*He takes off his shirt when restrained.*)

anagrams to

**Restrain the bear, son!**
(*Take control of the hairy creature, my male offspring!*)

Not a single word reused, so this has 100% new words.

Answer (score 0):

I care for you - choose: "abet", "abut", "acme", "acre", "acres"...

Your choices are: "rom", "beat", "tuba", "mace", "race", "scare"...

You can make this as long as you want until you run out of words. This question is poorly defined.

Comment: Question has been changed to address your loophole

Comment: Those sentences mean different things though. Besides, adding more characters adds *more* possibilities, not less.

Comment: All words must be changed in the new sentence. Look at the question and it will say that.

Comment: @warspyking: Fixed.

Comment: Okay... See **additional restrictions** AND keep in mind the meanings of the sentence must be different (which is not the case in your example)

Comment: @warspyking: You're changing the requirements as you go. And the meanings are clearly different - you're being asked to choose from a different set and being reassured in the first one only. "Find the longest anagram sentence *which will satisfy me*" is not a puzzle.

Comment: Puzzles are created to be improved, which this question is clearly helping. We're slowly making it more restrictive! Anyhow, your 2 sentences are essentially "Pick something from this list: ...", which is the same thing.

Comment: @warspyking: They have different lists and therefore different meanings. Would you claim that asking someone to pick a random number from 0-10 and 50-100 are the same thing? Meaning is subjective, and just trying to satisfy you is not a puzzle. The only restrictions being added are those that specifically disqualify answers that you don't happen to like.

Comment: No, the restrictions being added are to make it less broad and in effect, a better puzzle.

Comment: @warspyking: It's still too subjective. Meaning is interpreted by the listener. If you say "the dog barks at midnight", it could mean something completely different for a regular person and a secret agent, and all English sentences would mean nothing to someone who only speaks Russian. Puzzles should have one clear answer or one clear way of picking the best answer; this has neither. (Also, better solutions should in general be harder, not easier.)