# Make the question less broad

Tags: english, open-ended

Recently a question of mine was put on hold for being too broad: [Longest $Scramble Sentence$?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22019/longest-scramble-sentence)

Or if you prefer have this in the one window:

---

Before we begin, allow me to define what I call a **Scramble Sentence**,

> A *Scramble Sentence* is a grammatically correct sentence, where at least 1 other permutation, of the letters in the sentence, exists that it makes a different sentence with a different meaning.

Let's define a quick restriction though, just to make sure it isn't too easy, **NO WORDS CAN BE REUSED!**

The aim of this question is to find the **longest possible sentence which fits all of the above conditions!**

Note: *Punctuation doesn't count as part of the sentence (you don't have to scramble commas and such)*

**Additional restrictions:**
* No listing out words
* No quotation marks

---

It was supposed to be a fun and interesting question so that users can "compete" to find the longest sentence that can be rescrambled into a completely different sentence.

But my question for you guys, is how should I make that puzzle **less broad**, and limit the possible answers. I hope to learn from these suggestions and to improve my puzzle creating skills for the future!

Comment: This isn't a meta question... This is a question about creating a puzzle that obviously isn't fully defined yet. It isn't specific to the Puzzling SITE.

Comment: I'd add in 'no proper nouns'.

Comment: Each letter of the alphabet can only be used once.

Comment: I think this question itself might be too broad - there are an unlimited number of ways to limit the scope of the question. This might sound like a silly request, but could you possibly limit the scope of possible answers to this question by, as a suggestion, specifying exactly what it is you want this puzzle to be/how you'd like it to work?

Comment: @warspyking A question about how this question can be made less broad then?

Comment: @Emrakul like that?

Comment: @warspyking: The problem is that if you have more letters to work with, it gets *EASIER* to find possibilities.

Comment: @Deusovi I do not agree. FINDING permutations of "*Hello, I love toy trains!*" is easier than something longer like "*As he slowly crept down the hall, he heard thunder vibrating the walls, shaking his whole body with every step he took.*"

Comment: More letters give you more options to work with. Type a seven letter string into your preferred anagram generator online (that handles multiple words), then do it with a 23 more letters added on.

Comment: @Deusovi But it becomes more difficult to discover because it takes longer for example to find scrambles. However thanks for the idea of [tag:no-computers]

Comment: @warspyking: That's not more difficult, it just takes a longer time. My point is that the more letters you add, the more possibilities for valid words there are - increasing at a far faster rate than the difficulty of finding them does. And the computer thing was just an example.

Answer (score 3):

This question can be made less broad with any of the following conditions:

- only names of cities may be used
- you may only use the letter 'b'
- limit your answer to no more than two words
- words may not scramble into words previously used
- words may only scramble to words beginning with x
- both sentences must mention pears

Comment: +1, these certainly limit possible answers and would make me far more interested in seeing solutions.

Comment: Is `sreap` a word? If not, do both sentences have to mention exactly pears?